# Bot framework Emulator - deploy bot on premise and install on teams

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create a `Microsoft Teams Bot` using `Bot framework Emulator` that I can deploy on premise and install on Microsoft Teams.

I have a simple Bot, that I start on `Bot Framework Composer`, and works just fine when I click "Start bot".

1. I've exported the bot as zip
   [image]
2. I've run it using `Visual Studio 2019`, which works ok.
3. I've tried to connect using the `Bot Framework Emulator`, which works ok.
4. I've deployed the same bot on local IIS, I've managed to connect to the bot using  `Bot Framework Emulator`.

**What doesn't work**

I've deployed the bot to a remote server. When I try to use the emulator, it doesn't work anymore.
The error I get is `Error: The bot is remote, but the service URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies.`

In `Microsoft Teams` using `App Studio` I've done the following steps:

1. Create new app using the following feature [image]
2. Fill the inputs in the "App Details" and generate a new `App ID`, the generated AppId, i set on `appsettings.json` for the key `MicrosoftAppId`
   [image]
3. On "Bots" menu, I've set up a new bot.
   [image]
4. Configure the "Messaging endpoint address"
5. On "Test and distribute" click on install your app in teams for testing.

The bot is really quiet, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to run a bot on Teams from local. I didn't understand why you are trying to do with `Bot Framework Emulator`.

In order to debug and run bot on Teams from local, here are the two ways you can do that:

1. [Debug a bot from any channel using ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-channel-ngrok?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). It requires a subscription to [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/).
2. If you don't have azure subscription, you can try doing with App Studio. You are doing all right just you need to put `https://example.ngrok.io/api/messages` URL or public facing URL of service your bot is deployed, in messaging endpoint.

To run ngrok, here is the command `ngrok http 44327 -host-header=localhost:44327`. Change the port accordingly, you can checkout `Properties -> launchSettings.json` to know your port or to change(in c#).

Some useful docs:

1. [Prerequisites: Get started with Microsoft Teams app development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/prerequisites?tabs=vscode)
2. [Build your first conversational bot for Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/first-app-bot?tabs=vscode)